# In NGINX remove .html extension from URI without redirect

Tags: regex, nginx, webserver, uri

I'm trying to modify my NGINX config to strip the .html extension from URI's before they are passed to my PHP based CMS.

In other words when a visitor enters:

http://www.example.com/foo.html

I want the  URI to be changed to/;

http://www.example.com/foo

Without doing an actual browser redirect. This is easy enough to accomplish in Apache, but I can't seem to crack the nut in NGINX. Here is what I have in my config file that doesn't seem to work.

```
    location ~ \.html {
            rewrite ^(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 last;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/  /index.php;       
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
    }
```

Using this code the REQUEST_URI that PHP picks up is still /foo.html.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer to my own question, or at least a workaround.

So apparently $request_uri is always going to contain the original URI, not the rewrite - that is contained in $uri. So to workaround this I'm using a variable to store and pass the modifed URI to PHP. I'm not really thrilled with this solution though.

```
location ~ \.html {
            rewrite ^(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 last;
    }

    location / {
        set $new_uri $uri
        try_files $uri $uri/  /index.php;       
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $new_uri;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
    }
```